# GarbageCollector Dictionary<Int64, WeakReference<Object>> grows up in my WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm developing a navigated WPF Windows App based on pages, and i have some problem with weak references. I develop my App with the tips from this [blog](http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.de/2010/05/memory-leaks-in-wpf-applications.html), and i have no problem with memory but...

Every time when UI will by navigated to other page, grows the week references Dictionary. I call RemoveBackEntry and GC.Collect but it isn't the issue. 
Dictionary grows still up.

[image: Memory usage]

The Problem is actually, when it grows to much take the GC to much time to collect and it blocks all other threads of my software, and because of some critical communication thread i cannot allow it.

Did someone had the same problem and solved it?

Comment: Do you use async/await pattern in your application?

Comment: I don't use async/await, i use several threads, and separate thread for call the garbage collector

Comment: Your thread still can block UI threads. It depends on how you initialized those threads.

Comment: it is not the problem that my thread blocks the UI. The problem is that GC take to long time and GC block my thread.